# Output after specific post in the loop

Tags: plugins, loop

I'd like to hook into the loop with a plugin, and output some code after a post index in the loop. Two example I can think of are:

- output code after the 1st post in the loop
- output code in the middle (after num posts / 2)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no purposely provided hook available for this. The only hooks inside the loop are triggered at the start and the end of the hook.

There is `the_post` action, but this is probably far too generic to use (may cause undeseriable side effects) and is called a the wrong point for example:

The function used to iterate through the loop is `the_post()` which calls `setup_postdata()` to 'set up' the current post in the loop (sets up all the globals etc). This function triggers the action `the_post`.

... So this will be called at the top of the 'content' part of the post (typically - though not guaranteed - above the mark-up for the post).

Secondly, themes/plugins could cause `the_post` to be called from within the loop for things other than the current post in the loop, While you can ensure your callback is only triggered in between the start & end of the loop, you can't be sure that all the times its triggered in between is when you intend your callback to run.